# Проблема с ffmpeg и музыкальным ботом в Discord

Tags: discord.py, heroku

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]есть бот в дискорде, все работает если запущен у меня на компьютере, а если запускаю на heroku звук не воспроизводится, бот заходит ко мне в канал, в чате отображает что играет песня, но звука нет.
На heroku установлен ffmpeg, но при этом все равно звука нет

Comment: вот компьютер на heroku и играет. только это далеко от вас, потому и не слышите.

Answer (score 0):

При перед тем, как загружать данные и код, зайдите на странице вашего приложения во вкладку **Settings**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем промотайте до раздела **Buildpacks** и нажмите на кнопку **Add buildpack**.

Туда необходимо добавить две ссылки - FFMPEG и OPUS. Второй, вроде бы, тоже нужен для нормальной работы.

https://github.com/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest.git

https://github.com/xrisk/heroku-opus.git

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После этого, все должно заработать. Если, конечно, правильно написан код, и на Heroku установлены все необходимые модули.

Comment: Работает, спасибо!